# What is the best way to use count in eloquent? How can I get more performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, performance

I have to improve the performance of an application in Laravel. But I'm in doubt! How can I get more performance?

Use the count like this:

```
$users = User::all()->count();
```

or
before getting users:

```
$user->count;
```

I want to do the counting in the database itself and not in the controller.

Comment: [`$users = User::count();`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#retrieving-aggregates) uses aggregates and not the collection to count all entries.

Answer (score 0):

The raw you need is

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users
```

is optimal.  And it gives you the up-to-the-second value.  (I assume you want that since you said "I want to do the counting in the database itself".)  There are other ways to get an estimate that could be faster.

Saying `COUNT(id)` also checks `id` for being `NOT NULL` to decide whether to count the row.  Hence, it *may* be slower.

Sorry, I don't know how to translate that into Lauravel (or the dozens of other platforms that obfuscate the SQL).